# What does this 件 mean at the end of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana, kanji-choice

I saw this on a youtube comment:

**アメリカが正義を騙る度に邪悪さが鮮明に浮かび上がる件。**

I think it means something to the effect of:

*Every time America pretends to be about justice, its evil clearly emerges.*

But I translated this with the 件 omitted. What difference does it make if it is included or not, and how does the sentence change?

Comment: "You know how..." "You know the thing where..." "That..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it’s like saying this as we do in emails:

> Subject: Every time America pretends to be…

But nowadays, we also use it to say things in a funny way. Here’s my guess: 件 is more like a formal word, so it’s a bit awkward to say it in a casual conversation and that makes us feel it funny.

There’s a manga named 転生したらスライムだった件, which is exactly the case.

We have another word 説 similar to 件, but the topic has to be your assumption.

> 四国がオーストラリアに変わっていても意外と気付かない説